# Does viscosity of a liquid depend on object immersed?

Tags: physical-chemistry, viscosity

Just like coefficient of friction $\mu$, is coefficient of viscosity $\eta$ also a combined property of two media?

I performed an experiment to calculate coefficient of viscosity. The viscous liquid was kept in a burrete, which was kept exactly vertical (so as to prevent the object from touching the walls of container, so that no further frictional drag acts from the walls). The reading of the burrete (i.e. the distance fallen by the ball) was recorded for every 5s interval of time, and a y vs t graph was plotted. When the slope of y vs t graph attains a constant value, the ball can be assumed to have attained terminal velocity. Then we use $F_v + F_b = F_g$ , also since I was working for spherical objects, $F_v$ from Stoke's Law, can be given as $6 \pi \eta r v$. Substituting values we get

$$\eta = \frac{mg - \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_{liq} g}{6 \pi r v}.$$

I was working with Castor oil, so $\rho_{liq} = 0.84 g/cc$. This is my observation table:

[image: table]

Does coefficient of viscosity of a particular liquid also depend on the object immersed or there is some error in my experiment?

Please pardon me because my question is a yes,no type question. I am asking this question because I didn't find any information regarding this on web.

Comment: You should be aware that there can be other, really crazy physics involved. Especially because the other ball is of tiny mass, the other physics can really change the behaviour. And that is as much as I can reveal from my insane answer key.

Answer (score 3):

No. The viscosity does not depend on the shape of the object. In your case, it's just that there are biases in your measurement method.

First, Stokes' law only applies to Reynolds numbers much lower than 1. However, when you change the diameter of the ball the speed of the ball changes and therefore the Reynolds number too. It would therefore be necessary to verify that the Reynolds number is much less than 1 in both cases.

Even when it applies, Stokes' law assumes that there are no walls near the ball: the diameter of the ball must be much smaller than that of the tube in which it falls. Again, the diameter of the ball comes into play and if it is too large, corrections must be made.

You will find how to correct your measurements in the following link:

[High precision falling ball viscosimeter](https://hal.science/file/index/docid/197586/filename/Brizard.pdf)

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 2):

No. It only depends on the fluid.

When an object moves through a fluid at slow speeds, flow is laminar. For faster speed there is a much more complex turbulent flow.

Either way, fluid near the object flows at different speeds relative to the object. Close to the object it is near the speed of the object. Right at the surface, the speed is $0$ relative to the object.

So there is no friction from the fluid sliding over the object. The friction all comes from one layer of fluid "sliding over" the adjacent layer.